# SessionNotCreatedError: A new session could not be created. Details: 'autoGrantPermissions' must be of type boolean type

Tags: android-studio, appium, desiredcapabilities

unable to execute the Tests after "autoGrantPermissions=${booleanTrue}" introduced can any one help me with that everthing is upadted to latest version UI Automator 2 and other things are all updated

Tried to allow permission popups internally